# Implementing Dead Reckoning in a Winsock server

Tags: c++, networking

I'm having a little difficulty understanding how I implement Dead Reckoning in my Server-Client Winsock game.

I've been looking on the internet for a decent explanation that explains exactly:

1. When a message should be sent from the server to the client
2. How the client should act if it doesn't receive update messages, does it keep using the predicted position as the current position in order to calculate the new predicted position?

Should note I am using Linear Dead Reckoning using the following formula:

```
path vector = oldPosition - oldestPosition
delta time = oldTime - oldestTime
delta velocity = path vector / delta time
new delta time = current time / oldest time
new prediction = oldPosition + new delta time * delta velocity
```

Hope this is the correct one! :)

Should also note the connection type is UDP and that the game is played only on the server. The server sents update messages to the client.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: The Obligatory Gaffer Reference: http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/what-every-programmer-needs-to-know-about-game-networking/ should get you started.  After that discussions evolve into wibbly wobbly timey wimey stuff which is usually genre specific.

Comment: @PatrickHughes Love the reference :P